# Use Owl Carousel Url Hash Navigation to Change Button Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

Here is my owl carousel HTML and javascript.

HTML:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
   <div class="item" data-hash="slide1">
      <img src="images/mainslider.png">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Paragraph Text</p>
   </div>
   <div class="item" data-hash="slide2">
      <img src="images/mainslider.png">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Paragraph Text</p>
   </div>
   <div class="item" data-hash="slide3">
      <img src="images/mainslider.png">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Paragraph Text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

      navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      items : 1, 
      itemsDesktop : false,
      itemsDesktopSmall : false,
      itemsTablet: false,
      itemsMobile : false,
      URLhashListener:true,
      autoplayHoverPause:true,
      startPosition: 'URLHash'
  });
```

I have a navigation block below it that uses Url Hash Navigation.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default secondary-navbar">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#slide1">Slide 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#slide2">Slide 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#slide3">Slide 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

When a slide is clicked to or comes on screen, I need the corresponding link to change it's styles to show it is the one currently active.

I haven't found any native way to do this in Owl Carousel and wasn't sure how to accomplish this with Javascript

Comment: Could you please create a `fiddle`?

Comment: ya ill try to set one up. havent really used jsfiddle before

Comment: I couldnt figure how to set one up that would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around for a long time, I came up with the solution.

1. Add #link as class in hash navigations, and one more additional class in this case "slidetabs" e.g. `<a class="night_tubing slidetabs" href="#night_tubing">NIGHT TUBING</a>`
2. Get the current slide item and then its data-hash
3. Feed that data hash as a class in on changed function for adding class to navigation button
4. Then repeat same for change event to remove active class
5. Add a css to .slidetabs.active

`$('.owl-carousel').on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  var current = event.item.index;
  var hash = $(event.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).find(".item").attr('data-hash');
  $('.'+hash).addClass('active');
});`

`$('.owl-carousel').on('change.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  var current = event.item.index;
  var hash = $(event.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).find(".item").attr('data-hash');
  $('.'+hash).removeClass('active');
});`

**Note: this is works as expected so I have not worked any further on it, there may be better solutions with good coding out there.**

**following is the full code:**

Slider HTML:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">
   <div class="owl-stage-outer">
      <div class="owl-stage">
         <div class="owl-item">
            <div class="item" data-hash="cowboy_coaster">
               <!-- Slide Content -->
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="owl-item">
            <div class="item" data-hash="night_tubing">
               <!-- Slide Content -->
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- . -->
         <!-- . -->
         <!-- . -->
         <!-- . -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="owl-nav">
   <button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-prev">
      <img class="slider-arrow" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/slider-arrow-pre.png">
      <div class="slider-counter">1 / 4</div>
   </button>
   <button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-next"><img class="slider-arrow" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/slider-arrow-next.png"></button>
</div>
<div class="owl-dots disabled"></div>
<div class="owl-slider-tabs">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a class="dining slidetabs active" href="#dining">DINING</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a class="night_tubing slidetabs" href="#night_tubing">NIGHT TUBING</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a class="cowboy_coaster slidetabs" href="#cowboy_coaster">COWBOY COASTER</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a class="lift_tickets slidetabs" href="#lift_tickets">LIFT TICKETS</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.owl-carousel').on('initialized.owl.carousel changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
    if (!e.namespace)  {
      return;
    }
    var carousel = e.relatedTarget;
    $('.slider-counter').text(carousel.relative(carousel.current()) + 1 + ' / ' + carousel.items().length);
    }).owlCarousel({
      nav:true,
      navText: ["<img class='slider-arrow' src='/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/slider-arrow-pre.png'><div class='slider-counter'>1 / 3</div>","<img class='slider-arrow' src='/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/slider-arrow-next.png'>"],
      loop:true,
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      items:1,
      dots:false,
      URLhashListener:true,
      startPosition: 'URLHash',
      autoplay:true,
      autoplayTimeout:9000,
      autoplayHoverPause:true,
      animateOut: 'fadeOut',
      animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        1000:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        }
    }
  });

    $('.owl-carousel').on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
      var current = event.item.index;
      var hash = $(event.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).find(".item").attr('data-hash');
      $('.'+hash).addClass('active');
    });

    $('.owl-carousel').on('change.owl.carousel', function(event) {
      var current = event.item.index;
      var hash = $(event.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).find(".item").attr('data-hash');
      $('.'+hash).removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.slidetabs.active {
    color: #ce2d27;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Owl Carousel supports this natively, see here in the docs:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-classes.html

Comment: thanks for the page suggestion. i had found that one already but I really don't understand any of it or how it works. My knowledge of Javascript is very limited. Thanks for the reference though